# how to display excel data in body of the outlook automatically

Tags: excel, outlook-2007

how to display excel data in body of the outlook automatically

When i click a command button in excel sheet the data which is present in that particular sheet should be pasted in body of the outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ron de Bruin has VBA code for any conceivable scenario between Excel and Outlook.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm

Select what you need, for example "Mail one sheet" or "Mail one worksheet in the body of the mail".

If you need more specific help, post your code.